# Cloud Run deploy failing when using --command flag

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy to cloud run using it's `--command` flag option (see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy) but it fails anytime I try it. I do not know if I am not understanding how to use it or if it is something happening in google cloud's side.

My Dockerfile looks like the following:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["main.py"]
```

And I am deploying it with:

```
gcloud run deploy \
    $SERVICE \
    --image $IMAGE \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --memory $MEMORY \
    --concurrency $CONCURRENCY \
    --cpu $CPU \
    --platform managed \
    --region $REGION \
    --command "main2.py"
```

The logs are as follows:

```
X Deploying... Internal error occurred while performing container health check.                                                                     
  - Creating Revision...                                                                                                                            
  . Routing traffic...                                                                                                                              
  ✓ Setting IAM Policy...                                                                                                                           
Aborted by user.                                                                                                                                    
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Aborted by user.
```

Y tried also using only `CMD` in the Dockerfile (replace 2 last lines with `CMD python main.py`) and using `--command "python main2.py"` without success. I want to use the same Docker image but being able to deploy to run `main.py` (as default in Dockerfile) or `main2.py`

Note that if the `--command` flag is omitted it is deployed successfully and the app works.

The test code is at https://github.com/charlielito/cloud-run-test

The python code is just a dummy flask server. The main2.py is the same for testing purposes, just changed the response string.

```py
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    name = os.environ.get("NAME", "World")
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

Comment: what are the logs that you have in Cloud Logging?

Comment: Include **main.py** in your question. Your program must start an HTTP listener on port 8080 (or optionally the port specified in the deploy command).

Comment: It shows no logs at all. The main.py is now included and the deployment works just fine if I omit the `--command` flag

Comment: Since you are using **ENTRYPOINT**, the **--command** does not override that value but I have not verified that with Cloud Run. I think you need to use the **CMD** syntax in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I already tried also using only **CMD** syntax without success. According to GCP docs: `Entrypoint for the container image. If not specified, the container image's default Entrypoint is run` (at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy) which is also very confusing

Comment: Edit your question and add the Dockerfile that you used for the **CMD** syntax.

Comment: It is the same Dockerfile replacing the 2 last lines with with `CMD python main.py`

Comment: Do not put important details in your comments, edit your question, and include the entire Dockerfile and the error message/logs using that Dockerfile.

Comment: Could you confirm if you have tried the following steps:
1) Try ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"] by removing CMD in dockerfile or
2) update gcloud run command to use --command "python main2.py".